# remove blue background from markers

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, openstreetmap

how to remove the blue background from the markers?
this happen using default icon and a custom one (png with transparent background)

am I doing something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@picocss/pico@1/css/pico.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <title>Map with OpenStreetMap</title>
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([45.418393, 10.969487], 13); // Replace with your default map center

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        var marker = L.marker([45.410051797705904, 10.90330758434609]).addTo(map);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

tried with a custom icon but still got the same problem

```
var LogoPin = L.icon({
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    iconUrl: './pin.png',
    shadowUrl: './shad.png',
    iconSize:     [30, 47], // size of the icon [38,95]
    shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow*/
    iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow*/
    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
    
});

L.marker([place.lat, place.lng], {icon: LogoPin}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: done already in first attemp. pin.png has a transparent background, and problem is showing up even with default icon

Comment: Looks like downgrading to Leaflet version 1.7.1 restores the correct appearance: https://plnkr.co/edit/1bFOvZhrNQFrvDSK

Comment: Picocss seems to be the culprit: https://plnkr.co/edit/2C4336ncy8Kkersl

Answer (score 2):

It is found that you are using pico.css (I believe for your specific purposes)

For your information, pico css will apply background and border color to a number of elements, and it affects your marker background and border

For your case, if you want to remove the blue color around the marker, one of the ways is to add the following below the pico.css:

```
<style>

[role=button],button,input[type=button],input[type=reset],input[type=submit]{
    --background-color:none;
    --border-color:none;
}

[role=button]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),button:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),input[type=button]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),input[type=reset]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),input[type=submit]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus){
    --background-color:none;
    --border-color:none;
}

</style>
```

On the other hand, if you do not need shadow then comment them out:

```
//          shadowUrl: '',
//          shadowSize:   [50, 64],
//          shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
```

So the whole code (without background color around the marker) but preserving the use of pico.css will be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@picocss/pico@1/css/pico.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

<style>

[role=button],button,input[type=button],input[type=reset],input[type=submit]{
    --background-color:none;
    --border-color:none;
}

[role=button]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),button:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),input[type=button]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),input[type=reset]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),input[type=submit]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus){
    --background-color:none;
    --border-color:none;
}

</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .leaflet-container {
            height: 400px;
            width: 600px;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    
</head>
<body>



<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>

    const map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

//  const marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);


const LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
        options: {
//          shadowUrl: '',
            iconSize:     [32, 32],
//          shadowSize:   [50, 64],
            iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
//          shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
            popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
        }
    });

    const greenIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/library_maps.png'});

    const mGreen = L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('StackOverflow.com is good').addTo(map);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Result of the above code

[image]

Comment: Please note that OP explicitly uses Leaflet, not OpenLayers.

Comment: @ghybs, Thank you. I have further edited my answer and now it allows OP to continue using pico.css but at the same time fixing the problem of background color of marker

Comment: @KenLee thank you for your help. I just fixed all following official guide of leaflet: https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/